# How do I know where exactly my .reg will be installed in the registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit, product-key, serial-number

I am going to install a .reg file and I want to know, where exactly in my registry will it be installed? Is there a way to find out the registry path?
I want to locate the 20 character serial number included in the .reg file.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find a serial for my program using regedit.exe?](http://superuser.com/questions/1099478/how-can-i-find-a-serial-for-my-program-using-regedit-exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the .reg in Notepad or any other text editor.
The first thing in a .reg file is the path, example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoDriveTypeAutoRun"=dword:00000091
```

You'll see something similar to this, the first part is the path and the second line is the key it's going to enter. In this case, this would disable autorun of a CD being put into a computer.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Okay - my key is encoded, is there a possible way to know in which way to decode it?

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen - Your key to what exactly?

Comment: A music making program - Fl Studio 12 by image-line

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen - It entirely depends on how the license key is encoded.  How is the license key encoded exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound - that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen - You need to edit your question, so what you actual want is clear, because currently it appears you are simply asking how .reg files work.

Comment: No - my question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the .reg file > Right Click > Edit with Notepad

View the key there and the location.

Comment: Okay -- I have done this but my key is encoded... is there a way to find out how to decode it into 20 characters?

Comment: Well, it depends how it is encoded. If you can supply where the key is from and the encoded key itself, then we can help more :)